# Using the property of continuity to prove that two functions are equal to each other at a specific point.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose $\mathbb{Q}^2=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be two continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $h(x)-g(x)=(0,0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}^2$.

> Let $y=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Prove: $h(y)=g(y)$

**My attempted approach:** First let $a$ be in the domain of $h$ and $g$. As $h$ and $g$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ then for all $\epsilon > 0, \exists \ \delta >0 $ such that $\Vert x -a \Vert < \delta$, $\Vert g(x)-g(a) \Vert < \epsilon$ and $\Vert h(x)-h(a) \Vert < \epsilon$. As the domain of $h$ and $g$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ if we can replace the point $a$ with $y$, and $f$ and $h$ are still continuous at that point $y$.

Therefore as we approach $y$ on either side the property $h(x)-g(x)=(0,0)$  will hold so that $h(y)-g(y)=(0,0)$. Therefore $h(y)=g(y)$ .

I am not sure if the above approach is correct, any comments is appreciated. (Including a better title.)

Comment: I think you're skipping some details, but the idea is correct. To flesh it out, take a sequence $y_n \in \Bbb Q^2$ which converges to $y$. Then $h(y_n) - g(y_n) = 0$ for all $n$, hence the limit is equal as well. Then use continuity to conclude that $h(y) = g(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $(x,y)$ iff for every sequence $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots$ that converges to $(x,y)$, $\varphi(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow \varphi(x,y)$.

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots$ be a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $\sqrt{2}$, and let $y_1, y_2, \dots$ be a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $\sqrt{3}$. Since $g$ and $h$ are continuous at $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$,
$$
h(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) - g(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}h(x_n,y_n)-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(x_n,y_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}0 - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}0 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n,y_n)$ defined by

$x_0=y_0=1$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-2}{2x_n}$$

and

$$y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac{y_n^2-3}{2y_n}$$

for every $n\geq 0$.

$(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are two rational sequences which converge respectively to $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

thus

$$\forall n\in \mathbb N \;\; h(x_n,y_n)=g(x_n,y_n)$$

and by continuity,

when $ n \to +\infty$, we get

$$h(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=g(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}).$$

The idea here comes from Newton-Raphson's method.